# gVim utf-8 in windows

Tags: windows, vim, gvim, utf-8

When I open gVim it's localized to Sweidish, which is fine. But warning/error messages that have Swedish characters in them don't display correctly. When trying to delete a buffer with unsaved changes for example I get this:

```
E89: Ingen skrivning sedan senaste <e4>ndring f<f6>r buffert 1 (l<e4>gg till ! f<f6>r att tvinga)
```

Which roughly translates to

```
E89: No write since last edit for buffer 1 (append ! to force)
```

What I want is this:

```
E89: Ingen skrivning sedan senaste ändring för buffert 1 (lägg till ! för att tvinga)
```

These are a couple of relevant settings:

```
> :language
  Aktuellt spr<e5>k: "LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252;LC_CTYPE=C;LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252"
> :lang mes
  Aktuellt message spr<e5>k: "SV"
> :set enc
  encoding=utf-8
```

How do I make vim display the proper characters (å, ä, ö) instead of the `<e5>`, `<e4>`, `<f6>` codes?

**EDIT:** Trying `:language sv_SE.UTF-8"` I get `E197: Can not set the language to "sv_SE.UTF-8`

**EDIT2:** I have tried:

```
:language Swedish_Sweden.10646
:language sv_SV.UTF-8
:language en
:language en_EN.UTF-8
```

All with the same E197 error message.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved it. It was actually hinted at on the vim web page. http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc

I had to get two files from [the gettext project on sourcforge](http://sf.net/projects/gettext):

- [libiconv-1.9.1.bin.woe32.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gettext/files/libiconv-win32/1.9.1/libiconv-1.9.1.bin.woe32.zip/download) (for iconv.dll)
- [gettext-runtime-0.13.1.bin.woe32.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gettext/files/gettext-win32/0.13.1/gettext-runtime-0.13.1.bin.woe32.zip/download) (for intl.dll)

Extract bin/iconv.dll from the libiconv zip and bin/intl.dll from the gettext zip in to your gVim/vim folder. Rename intl.dll to libintl.dll. Overwrite any existing files.

After that it just worked for me. These are the relevant lines from my _vimrc:

```
if has('gui_running')
    set guifont=Courier_New:h10
endif

set encoding=utf-8
```

They are placed at the top of _vimrc.

Answer (score 0):

If I do "`:lang sv_SE.UTF-8`" then the messages show up correctly for me, but this is under Linux and I'm not sure if that will work in Windows.

Comment: When I try that I get: 'E197: Can not set the language to "sv_SE.UTF-8"'

Answer (score 0):

To make ÅÄÖ åäö work in vim,
you need to set your Terminal client like PUTTY to use UTF-8.

This has nothing to do with vim or .vimrc

Comment: it's been talking about the gui version of vim. This has nothing to do with the terminal